# How to add "id" attribute in form element using MVC4

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I tried to add id attribute in form element using the following code:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("<action>", "<controller>", new {id="search"}))
```

I got the following code in source view:

```
<form action='/controller/action/search' method="post">
```

I need to add "id" attribute. How to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 @using(Html.BeginForm("<action>", "<controller>",FormMethod.Post, new {id="search"}))
```